# Selectors in ngRx 4 returning store object instead of a value in the store

Tags: angular, ngrx-store-4.0

My selector is returning the store object instead of the value from the store when i am trying to retrieve data.

Here is my reducer injection.

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    StoreRouterConnectingModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot({ 'home': reducer, 'router': routerReducer }),
    StoreRouterConnectingModule,
    StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({ maxAge: 50 }),
  ]
```

Here is my reducer and state.

```
export interface State {
  version: number;
}

export const initialState: State = {
  version: 1
};

export function reducer(state= initialState, action: Action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

and here is my selector.

```
import { createFeatureSelector, createSelector } from '@ngrx/store';
import * as fromRoot from './app.reducer';

export const getHomeData = createFeatureSelector<fromRoot.State>('home');

export const getVersionNumber = createSelector(
    getHomeData,
    (store) => store.version
);
```

the output that i am getting is

[Here is my console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQReZ.png)

```
Store {_isScalar: false, actionsObserver: ActionsSubject, reducerManager: ReducerManager, source: Store, operator: DistinctUntilChangedOperator}
actionsObserver
:
ActionsSubject
operator
:
DistinctUntilChangedOperator
reducerManager
:
ReducerManager
source
:
Store
_isScalar
:
false
__proto__
:
Observable
```

This is how i am accessing my selectors.

```
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(public store: Store<State>) {
    console.log(this.store.select(getVersionNumber));
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i am facing the same issue? Did you find the root cause of this?

Comment: @PankajSays its the behaviour of the observables, so if you want to apply any business logic for the data you can subscribe the value like, ~~ this.store.select(getVersionNumber).subscribe((value) => this.number = value); or else map the selector to the value and then use async pipe in your html file {{ number | async }}

Answer (score 0):

try to subscribe to observable via component

```
export class AppComponent {
  public getVersionNumber$: Observable<number>;
  constructor(public store: Store<State>) {
    getVersionNumber$ = this.store.select(getVersionNumber)
                        .pipe(
                          tap(versionNumber => console.log(versionNumber))
                         )
                         .subscribe();
  }
}
```

which is not 100% clean because you have to handle unsubscription.
It would be better if you can find a place in temple to hook subscription like:

```
 // component
    export class AppComponent {
      public getVersionNumber$: Observable<number>;
      constructor(public store: Store<State>) {
        getVersionNumber$ = this.store.select(getVersionNumber)
                            .pipe(
                              tap(versionNumber => console.log(versionNumber))
                             );
      }
    }

// somewhere in template
<ng-container *ngIf="(getVersionNumber$ | async) as getVersionNumber">
{{getVersionNumber}}
</ng-container>
```

async pipe will automatically handle the subscription